# How to tell if WCF service client proxy has timed out

Tags: c#, wcf, wshttpbinding

I have a WCF service using wsHttpBinding with message encryption. I use the same service reference unless it has become faulted, in which case I create a new one. I'm running in to an issue where the session has timed out and the service has closed its end, but the client application still has the CommunicationState as Opened.

How can I tell in ClientBase if the connection has timed out? I want in my client application to create a new service proxy if the current one has timed out.

Below is my client-side binding:

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingWithAuthClient" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Why cannot you create new proxy each time?

Comment: I'd have to set up my ClientCredentials each time, and ServiceCertificate fields. I'm not sure of the ramifications of doing that for each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just wrap all of your service calls in a try/catch, and in the catch block of the specific exception type of server connection timeout, recreate the proxy.

```
try
{
  serviceProxyGlobal.Method()
}
catch(WhateverServerTimeoutException ex)
{
  serviceProxyGlobal = new ServiceProxy();
  //retry maybe?
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  logException(ex);
}
```

Comment: This is good practice for retry, but doesn't answer my question. Is it unanswerable?

Comment: This is the only way to check if a WCF connection (with this type of binding) has timed out, to call a proxied method on it. It seems to answer the question. How else would you expect a client to tell if a server has closed its connection?

Comment: I expected there to be some simple method to call on the ClientBase like "IsAlive". That is why I asked the question. If this is the only way then I'll accept that.

Comment: It would be redundant though, you would call to the server twice, one to check if its alive and two in actually making your method call. Another solution to this is using duplex bindings ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx), but in most cases that is overkill just to check if a connection has been closed.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the server is closing the client connection. I wasn't actually sure if it was the client side being closed, or the server side. Looking at the server logs, it appears to be the server, since the client continues to use a secure session that is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider accessing that shared web service reference using a simple getter, where you basically try to "ping" your web service just before returning reference to it (that "ping" method should be really simple, like `Boolean Ping() { return true; }`) If it throws exception (here you have to cater for all possible scenarios), simply handle it, suppress it (if it's an exception you can identify and which you expected) and create new shared connection.

Alternatively you can design a method pinging your web service each [web service timeout in minutes] / 2 minutes in a background thread.